# Why does Java only accept overridden base class method with the same return type?

Tags: java, c#

My background in C#. I want to know why Java overridden base class method expects same return type, even if we change the overridden return type to be of the base class type it throws an error. Can anyone let me know the reason for this? Please find the code snippet from below.

```
public class ListIterator
     extends Test // Test is base for ListIterator
{
}

class Collection
{
    public ListIterator iterator() throws Exception {
        return new ListIterator();
    }
}


class Child 
    extends Collection
{
   //Here the return type “Test” is the base for ListIterator, but still it 
   //throws error to mark the return type as ListIterator. If we comment the 
   //extended base class "Collection" it works as expected.

    public Test iterator() throws Exception {
        return new ListIterator();
    }
}
```

Comment: "But the same behavior works in C#." No it doesn't - not if you're actually overriding. In fact, Java is more *lenient* here, in that an overriding method can return a more specific type. But it can't return a more *general* type, which is what you're trying to do.

Comment: On a separate note, it's Java, not JAVA.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, no, this wouldn't work in C# - not when you're actually overriding the method. (It will work if you use `new`, but then you're not overriding.) C# is more strict than Java, in that the return types do have to match exactly... whereas Java allows you to return a more *specific* type, just not a more general one. For example, this is fine:

```
public class Base {
    public Object getFoo() {
        ...
    }
}

public class Child extends Base {
    @Override public String getFoo() {
        ...
    }
}
```

... but you're trying to do the opposite.

To show why that's dangerous, imagine that you changed your `Child.iterator()` method implementation to `return new Test();`. Then imagine someone has written:

```
Collection collection = new Child();
ListIterator iterator = collection.iterator();
```

Everything looks perfectly type-safe, because `Collection.iterator()` is declared to return `ListIterator` - but the returned value is neither null nor a reference to a `ListIterator`.

So basically, the answer is "Java is protecting you from shooting yourself in the foot. This is a good thing."

Answer (score 1):

Subtypes must have the same or greater capabilities than their supertypes.  Formally this is known as the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

If `ListIterator` extends `Test`, then `ListIterator` may be more capable than `Test`, and presumably is, or else it would be pointless.

If `Child` extends `Collection`, then `Child` must not reduce the capabilities of `Collection` by returning a less capable type from one of its methods.

If this works in C#, then C# is broken.

Comment: Fortunately, C# isn't broken - the OP's understanding of it is, apparently.